# How should I convert a library of Bash functions to a library of Python functions for use in Bash?

Tags: python, bash, function, dependencies, environment

I have a huge library of Bash functions in a single file that is sourced in Bash, making all of the functions available for use through single commands in Bash.

These functions take normal arguments (e.g. input filename, output filename etc.), but they all also take the special argument `--interrogate`, which causes them not to run, but to report on their requirements and dependencies. When the library is sourced, it cycles through all of the functions, interrogating them, and determining if their dependencies (such as required programs) are available. If dependencies are not available, the library warns about this and offers to install them.

This approach has been working, but it is getting quite hard to manage and I'd really rather be working in Python, where I could define a class for Bash function objects etc.

So, how could I convert this library to Python? I'd want the various functions to be available in Bash using their individual names, not as arguments of a Python script.

Comment: In my experience most Bash scripts are so badly written that it is not worth trying to automate a conversion - of course that will not be the case here.  I suggest that you rewrite working from the documentation.  If you have not documented the library then maybe now is the time to do it.  That documentation can be placed inside `"""` and used as doc-strings.  It is difficult to give more detailed advice without seeing the code (or doc).

Comment: I see two options. 1. Reimplement each bash function in a different language from scratch (you probably try to avoid this). 2 (ugly one) Create a python wrapper for each bash function, start bash in child process, source the *.sh file containing the needed function, call the function, read the bash exit code in python, take the appropriate action according to the exit code (success/failure).

Comment: @cdarke The Bash library is well-written and documented (the functions are self-documenting actually). What I'm not sure about is how to make the functions in the Python version of the library available as commands in the Bash environment. So, I'd like to be able to run the Python script that is the new library and have it modify the Bash environment such that various new commands correspond to Python functions in the Python script.

Comment: Honestly I would forget trying to mix bash and python - you would have to run a bash process to run the functions in, and you might well end-up creating more problems than you solve.  It sounds like a rewrite to me.  How that is structured around modules and classes depends on the functionality of the library.

Comment: You can make your Python scripts available as commands in bash: start them with an appropriate shebang, put them somewhere in your PATH, and make them executable (`chmod +x`)

Comment: I suspect that if you give a short sketch of the specific code maybe, one function stripped down and the code that gets run when this is sourced we could work up a solution. Ideas that might be used are adding bash aliases to run the scripts. Having the python scripts work both as functions or not via `__name__ = __main_` and possibly `exec()`. But in the abstract with this little detail as to what you are doing, and what you want, and why, it would be hard to come up with something.